# Postgresql query: "greater than" statement returns values less than

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select the rows where the value of one column is greater than (>) the other column. However, it returns rows where the values are less than the other column.

If I use the less than operator (<), it returns rows where the values are less than the other column, just like expected. The only difference is the order of the rows.

The values of the columns are "varchar", which I've casted into "integer" for the query.

**Query**

`SELECT tripcode, CAST(expected AS int), CAST(capacity AS int) FROM super_plan WHERE expected > capacity;`

This is the result with the greater than (>) operator:

| expected | capacity |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | 310 |
| 50 | 250 |
| 80 | 270 |
| 60 | 270 |
| 60 | 340 |
| 80 | 340 |
| 80 | 250 |
| 70 | 360 |
| 50 | 360 |
| 80 | 360 |
| ... | ... |

**Query**

`SELECT tripcode, CAST(expected AS int), CAST(capacity AS int) FROM super_plan WHERE expected < capacity;`

This is the result with the less than (<) operator:

| expected | capacity |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 310 |
| 200 | 310 |
| 230 | 310 |
| 280 | 310 |
| 150 | 310 |
| 100 | 250 |
| 200 | 250 |
| 190 | 250 |
| 160 | 250 |
| 110 | 270 |
| ... | ... |

I don't know why this is happening. I'm new to sql. I've already searched the web and stackoverflow, but I couldn't find something usefull.

Comment: As a string `'60'` is greater than (ie lexicographically ordered later than) `'300'`, just as `'foo'` is greater than `'bar'`

Answer (score 4):

Actually the columns need to be cast to integers in the `WHERE` clause, where the comparisons are being made:

```sql
SELECT tripcode, expected, capacity
FROM super_plan
WHERE expected::int > capacity::int;
```

If you have a persistent need to use these columns as integers, perhaps consider changing the column types.